# Identity name does not display

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am building an aspnet.core mvc project with identity server 4. when I do this in my view:

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

I do not get anything displayed, but when I do this:

```
@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.ToLower() == "name").Value
```

I get the desired result displayed.  I am currently learning Identity Server 4, so I am just curious as to what the difference is, and if I am missing some logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClaimsIdentity` does not automatically know the type of your name claim. You need to set the `NameClaimType` property in your config, e.g. On the `TokenValidationParamters` on the OIDC middleware.

Same as for roles:
https://leastprivilege.com/2016/08/21/why-does-my-authorize-attribute-not-work/